# Why Python informixdb package is throwing an error!

Tags: python, informix

I have downloaded & installed the latest Python InformixDB package, but when I try to import it from the shell, I am getting the following error in the form of a Windows dialog box!

**"A procedure entry point sqli_describe_input_stmt could not be located in the dynamic link isqlit09a.dll"**

Any ideas what's happening?

Platform: Windows Vista (Biz Edition), Python 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of IBM Informix Connect (I-Connect) or IBM Informix ClientSDK (CSDK) are you using?  The 'describe input' function is a more recent addition, but it is likely that you have it.

Have you been able to connect to any Informix DBMS from the command shell?  If not, then the suspicion must be that you don't have the correct environment.  You would probably need to specify $INFORMIXDIR (or %INFORMIXDIR% - I'm going to omit '$' and '%' sigils from here on); you would need to set INFORMIXSERVER to connect successfully; you would need to have the correct directory (probably INFORMIXDIR/bin on Windows; on Unix, it would be INFORMIXDIR/lib and INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql or INFORMIXDIR/lib/odbc) on your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Does other way to connect to database work?
Can you use (configure in control panel) ODBC? If ODBC works then you can use Python win32 extensions (ActiveState distribution comes with it) and there is ODBC support. You can also use Jython which can work with ODBC via JDBC-ODBC bridge or with Informix JDBC driver.